# Transfering all data from one table to the other same database

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to move a complete row of records which includes BLOB from one table (TABLE1) to another table (TABLE2) in the same database using SQL. I have tried what little I know but it failed.

What I have already used which failed is:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
 WHERE 
staff_id = '0010002';
```

How should I do this instead?

Comment: well, if your table structure is not exactly the same this will run into errors. Try specifying them in the right order ( plus defaults ) column wise speaking, in your SELECT statment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2 (colname1, colname2)
SELECT colename1, colename2
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE staff_id = '0010002'
```

And for more details.http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html